# AWS terminated instance refuses to stay terminated

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I have 2 EC2 Micro instances. I've **stopped one of it several times and terminated it several times as well. But, for some reason it boots itself back up again**.

Not sure how or why this happens, but I'm being billed 10$ every month because of this. Is there some hidden AWS setting where it says start every terminated Instance?

All Google/aws results/doc's speaks about -- **Terminated instance will automatically get removed after 10-20min's**. but, in my case -- it automatically gets started.

Any help, pointers would be great.

Answer (score 0):

You are using some process that will auto launch instances if the previous ones were terminated.

This is often done with an autoscaling group that may have been created with elastic beanstalk.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer [here](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=115913)

It seems like you have been using Elastic Beanstalk. If you open up that section of the AWS Management Console, you can delete the application/environment from there. This will bring down the instance as well. When you terminate the Elastic Beanstalk instance manually through the EC2 section, the system thinks that it has failed and will launch a replacement.